# Add expires header conditionally based on mime type in nginx

Tags: nginx

Running nginx 1.4.1 on ubuntu 12.10

Need to send expires header conditionally and based on mime type/content type of http response.

Added this simple piece of code inside location / {

```
if ($sent_http_content_type = "text/css") { 
expires 7d;
}
```

The expires header is not sent even if  $sent_http_content_type contains "text/css"

How to fix this ?

Checking file extensions is not enough, because in my app js,css, images are being generated dynamically from php. So need to check the mime and add headers based on that too.

Comment: Why not just match the suffix of the file name?

Comment: @jeffatrackaid in my application js,css, images are generated dynamically from php scripts, which wont match file extension, hence i need to add expires and other headers with mime checking.

Comment: Why would you not set the expires header in the PHP script itself? That's the right layer to do it, especially if it can change based on the type of request and content. For example, some CSS might be give an 1 hour lifetime, but others might get only 10 minutes. Your application code knows this information at runtime, nginx cannot see inside your business logic.

Answer (score 21):

As of nginx 1.7.9:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
  default         off;
  application/pdf 42d;
  ~image/         max;
}

expires $expires;
```

NOTE: $sent_http_content_type is valid, but it cannot be accessed until the server has processed the request...

The answer is pointed at the map entry for `application/pdf` which allows a date value, or could even be `application/pdf    modified +42d` for example

Comment: For newer NGINX installations, this is the desired answer.

Comment: This example and more details, such as time syntax, can be found in the [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).

Answer (score 10):

The `if` directive in Nginx is processed early on at the rewrite stage, and hence the `$sent_http_content_type` variable has not yet been initialised - see [this nginx bug report](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/375) for details.

**EDIT**: *Comparing usernames, that bug report might well be you, actually!* (^_^)

Similarly, the `expires` directive doesn't seem to support variables in the same way that, for example, `add_header` does. So, since you're not in a position to statically specify the location based on file extensions, I can only think of two basic approaches.

One would be to use the `map` and `add_header` approach suggested by Vadim above to manually set HTTP headers instead of allowing the `expires` directive to do it. This is rather less flexible as it won't set the `Expires` header, but I'd hope that any browser these days would do the right thing with just `Cache-Control` being set. Here's an example that I've briefly tested:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $cacheable_types {
    "text/css"    "max-age=864000";
    "image/jpeg"  "max-age=864000";
    default       "";
}

# ...

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        # ...
        add_header "Cache-Control" $cacheable_types;
    }
}
```

The value **864000** is 10 days in seconds - you'll have to change this to whatever you wish. The advantage of this approach is that you can specify different times for each file type, and even override other aspects of the `Cache-Control` header - you discussion of this header [here](http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/), and the official part from the HTTP RFC [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) if you prefer something more formal.

The second approach would be to just arrange that requests that will result in cacheable content all come under a specific path that you can use in a `location` directive like this:

```
location / {
    # ...
    location /static {
        expires 10d;
    }
}
```

This makes the nginx configuration easier because you can use its builtin `expires` directive, but whether it's an option very much depends whether you can enforce that pattern of URLs on your code.

Comment: See my comment on Vadims... had an idea...

Answer (score 3):

$sent_http_content_type is invalid. Request header values can be accessed via $http_*name*. Also, for Content-type header nginx has embedded variable $content_type.

If you would like to check $content_type against bunch of types, it would be better to use map:

```
   map $content_type $test_header {
        "text/css"  OK;
        "text/html" OK;
        ...
        default "";
   }

   server {
        location / {
             add_header "X-Test" $test_header;
        }
   }
```

If $test_header evaluates to empty string, header will not be set.

For futher information, see:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: thanks for that, it can be used to add a header, but I am looking for more, need to use expires, based on mime type

Comment: Do you think you could put the expires value as per each `$content_type`? I.e. the map could use a $content_type value of 30d or 1y and then you could place that in `location /` with `expires $test_header`?

Comment: Ignore that... expires doesn't support it. However you could test against an if statement and place a hard value in expires... I'm currently having a go at that

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the mime-type, then try:

```
if ($content_type ~= "text/css") { 
expires 7d;
}
```

However, you may want to consider something like this:

```
location ~ \.(css|js|htc)$ {
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;

}
location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
         log_not_found off;
        access_log off;

}
location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mp
e|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$
 {
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;

}
```

We use this on a very busy site with very good effect.

Comment: i cannot test on file extension. in my application js,css and images are generated on the fly from php scripts. hence i need some mime based checking and enable expires.